# How to create an Auto-ID inside a firestore document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to achieve this for the friend request functionality in my data structure for sent requests, but I am unable to: 
[image: This is the structure of the sent_requests collection]

Essentially I am trying to pull this off from the Realtime Database in the Cloud firestore:
[image]
Above reqId1 and reqId2 are automatically generated Id's.
Its quite easy to pull this off in the Realtime db as I can just use the `push() method`.
The issue is not creating a random number, it is that I am unable to create a document with an autoID inside the userId document in which I shall store the data.

I have tried this:

```js
sendRequest() {
    const uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
    firestore()
      .collection('Sent_Reqs')
      .doc(`${uid}`)
      .collection(`${this.autoId()}`)
      .add({
        targetId: this.userId,
        sentAt: new Date(),
      });
  }
```

But the above doesn't do any good because it nests the data two levels inside the document(uid).

Please help me

Thank you

Comment: Please refer https://blog.jscrambler.com/getting-started-with-firestore-and-react-native/

Comment: @hongdevelop this doesn't solve my problem of creating a document with an AutoID inside a document(userId)

Comment: You can't create documents inside documents. Can you update your question to include the code that you tried? It's much more likely that we'll be able to help if we see the actual code that you're struggling with.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edited the question

Comment: Are you saying that you want to generate a random subcollection name?  That doesn't seem helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure on Firestore is always in pairs of *collection* and then *document* in there. The collection names are usually fixed/hard-coded names, while the document names are usually generated (or based on the data).

You can't immediately nest documents under another document, they must always be in a named collection. If there's no reason for you to have multiple subcollections, you can just pick any subcollection name that makes sense for you.

For example:

```
Sent_Requests
  (uid)
    Requests
      (request_id)
```

Here `Sent_Requests` and `Requests` are collection names, `(uid)` and `(request_id)` are document names. The `Requests` collection is not really helpful, but needed to satisfy the Firebase requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of your document data. I don't this firebase can help you on that.

If you are structuring the database this way just to fetch the request sent by particular user easiy. I would like to suggest another structure as follows:

```
Sent_Request (collection)
|-AutoID1 (document, this ID you can generate with help of firebase)
  |- targetUser : value
  |- sentAt : value
  |- requestSentBy : userId
|-AutoID2 (document, this ID you can generate with help of firebase)
  |- targetUser : value
  |- sentAt : value
  |- requestSentBy : userId
```

Comment: I thought of this but, won't this slow down querying if I have to retrieve the sent requests of a specific user??

Comment: No it won't. All first level data are being indexed by the firebase. So this structure won't affect the query performance.